# Zend Framework 2 Autodiscover complex type

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Someone managed create a complex type from a class. I have the next error

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getTypes()

```
$complex_type_strategy = new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\DefaultComplexType();
$complex_type_strategy->addComplexType('className');
$autodiscover->setComplexTypeStrategy($complex_type_strategy);
```

.....

```
class className {
    /**
    * @var string $field
    */
    public $field;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: where is getTypes() called from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it in this way:

```
<?php

use Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeComplex;

$autodiscover = new AutoDiscover(new ArrayOfTypeComplex());
$autodiscover->setClassMap(array('Application\Class\Document'));
$autodiscover->setUri('http://myws.me/ws');
$autodiscover->handle();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Using Autodiscover() without passing ArrayOfTypeComplex() will cause the generation of WSDL to fail if array of objects declaration in the phpdoc is present.